# How to write function in SparkR?

Tags: r, function, sparkr

I recently start using sparkR.
I am using Rstudio server.
when I run

```
rdd_str <- SparkR:::lapplyPartition(foo.keep_start, function(part){
part <- lapply(part, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ',')))
part <- lapply(part, function(x) as.numeric(x[x != '']))
part
}),
```

that's ok.

I want to apply 13 object(libs) at one go

```
libs <- c('cancel_count', 'cancel_refund', 'dead_count', 'dead_ratio.month',
      'discount.month', 'firat_year_count', 'dead_count', 'foo.cancel',
      'foo.keep_start', 'keep_count', 'pv.net', 'start_keep_count',
      'tatal')
```

how to write function?

Answer (score 1):

To write a function on SparkR you can do it as in R.

```
Var<-function(params){
  ...
}
```